# System error: The program can't start because MSVCP140D.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, system-error

So I have programmed a simple graphical snake game using SFML in visual studio 2015
and it runs perfectly on my main computer. And I thought that I should try it on my laptop. When running the program it gave me this error:
**System error: The program can't start  because MSVCP140D.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem**
So I searched it in my computer and found it so I copied it on my laptop and then again I received another error which was:
**Application error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.**
I tried reinstalling the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable and still it didn't work. (BTW it is not a code problem and I have installed SFML correctly and used its libraries and bins without any problem). Your help would mean a lot to me. Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
// 
GraphicalLoopSnakeGame.cpp : 
Defines the entry point for 
the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

int N = 30, M = 20;
int size = 16;
int w = size*N;
int h = size*M;

int dir, num = 4;

struct Snake
{
    int x, y;
}       s[100];

struct Fruit
{
    int x, y;
}   f;

void Tick()
{
    for (int i = num;i>0;--i)
{
        s[i].x = s[i - 1].x; 
        s[i].y = s[i - 1].y;
}

if (dir == 0) s[0].y += 1;
if (dir == 1) s[0].x -= 1;
if (dir == 2) s[0].x += 1;
if (dir == 3) s[0].y -= 1;

if ((s[0].x == f.x) && (s[0].y == f.y))
{
    num++; f.x = rand() % N; f.y = rand() % M;
}

if (s[0].x>N) s[0].x = 0;  if (s[0].x<0) s[0].x = N;
if (s[0].y>M) s[0].y = 0;  if (s[0].y<0) s[0].y = M;

for (int i = 1;i<num;i++)
    if (s[0].x == s[i].x && s[0].y == s[i].y)  num = i;
}

int main()
{
        srand(time(0));
        RenderWindow 
    window(VideoMode(w, h), 
"Snake Game!");

Texture t1, t2, t3; 
t1.loadFromFile("images/white.png");
t2.loadFromFile("images/red.png");
t3.loadFromFile("images/green.png");

Sprite sprite1(t1);
Sprite sprite2(t2);
Sprite sprite3(t3);

Clock clock;
float timer = 0, delay = 0.12;

f.x = 10;
f.y = 10;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    clock.restart();
    timer += time;

    Event e;
    while (window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) dir = 1;
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) dir = 2;
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)) dir = 3;
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)) dir = 0;

    if (timer>delay) { timer = 0; Tick(); }

    ////// draw  ///////
    window.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            sprite1.setPosition(i*size, j*size);  window.draw(sprite1);
        }

    for (int i = 0;i<num;i++)
    {
        sprite2.setPosition(s[i].x*size, s[i].y*size);  window.draw(sprite2);
    }

    sprite3.setPosition(f.x*size, f.y*size);  window.draw(sprite3);

    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please correct the indentation of the code?

Comment: Make sure to match the architecture of your program to that of the DLL. Failing that, just install both the 32-bit and 64-bit runtimes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using the debug visual studio runtime, if you want to try it on another computer you should recompile your code in release mode and make sure that the appropriate visual studio runtime redistributable is installed.

If you really need to run a debug executable on another machine you need to make sure you copy the correct runtime (32 or 64-bit according to how you've compiled your program), this can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.24.28127\debug_nonredist` (at least for visual studio 2019, the exact path will be slightly different depending on your visual studio version, e.g. visual studio 2015 uses `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist`).

Comment: Distributing the debug runtime is not covered by Visual Studio's license.

Comment: I am not using debug runtime (regular build) and also I am not trying it on another computer. I just downloaded Visual Studio 2022 and added C++ plugin and now I get this error.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned the PC is missing the runtime support DLLs for your program. I sugges you should download it from MS site and be sure there is no viruses: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145

**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.** Firstly I suggest to test whether there is a problem between your application and its dependencies using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

And then the Error Code means: 0xC000007B STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT. I think that you trying to use 64-bit DLL with 32-bit application (or vice versa).

Comment: You cannot download the debug runtime libraries.